# How to establish an OLE DB connection to a FoxPro .DBC file in SSIS when the file itself is located on a server (non-local)?

Tags: ssis, odbc, oledb, foxpro

I'm trying to import data from a .dbc file into an sql table.
In order to do that I need to create an OLD Db connection to the .DBC file created by a FoxPro program.

The connection test succeeds when the file is located locally on my G:\ drive.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bumv.jpg

The connection test fail when the file is located on a server.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWqf1.jpg

My user has all of the necessary permissions to use the .dbc file on server ALFA. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'OLD Db' ? 

What development platform are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro wrong. You don't specify a single file but a folder in which the .DBC files are stored.